# New web standards?

Tags: search-engine, web-standards

Google, Microsoft, & Yahoo now plan to create a new web standard.
Is this going to be an advantage to web developers using html, ajax as development?

Will there be no browser issues if this happens?

Are they doing this new standards to beat adobe's flash player, and mxml conventions?

What's the best move for web app development today in terms of GUI?
To develop using adobe's flex framework
OR to stay contemporary using various ajax toolkits/ frameworks (e.g. GWT, EXT, jQuery)?

Comment: I feel that this is highly subjective and argumentative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably mean the definition of a "canonical tag" ("[Google, Yahoo & Microsoft Unite On “Canonical Tag” To Reduce Duplicate Content Clutter](http://searchengineland.com/canonical-tag-16537)"):

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/products/apples"/>
```

It is just a way to tell search engines which URLs contain duplicate content. So, I guess it isn't something revolutionary. It won't affect most of the work done by web developers today and it won't resolve any brower issues.

From [here](http://itvoir.com/portal/news/Corporate-News/Google-Yahoo-Microsoft-to-Support-new-Web-Standard.asp):

> According to the estimates around 20
>   percent of URLs on the web are
>   duplicate. Many web publishers, like
>   e-commerce companies, have multiple
>   URLs that all point to the same page.
>   This confuses search engines,
>   sometimes causing them to index the
>   same page multiple times.

Comment: thanks. i think  i just misinterpreted what i read.haha. i thought they would do do something to solve browser issues..:(